# Kendo grid insert new row with custom class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is how I insert new data to kendo grid, however i want my added row have a custom class, so I can style my new added row with different background color. How can I achieve this ? I searching all the doc can't find any related

```
    var dataSource = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;
    dataSource.insert(0, {
        "name":"ABC",
        "age": 99
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add a new class to each newly row you can use [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/). But, every time you move to the next/prev page or add other rows you need to add again the class....

In order to achieve that you can save in a global array a list of all newly added row uuid and on [dataBound event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound#databound) reapply the class.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sx1Lkv43/1/)

```js
var newUUID = [];
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    navigatable: true,
    filterable: true,
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 5,
        alwaysVisible: false,
        pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 100]
    },
    dataBound: function(e) {
        $.each(newUUID, function(idx, ele) {
            if ($(ele).length != 0) {
                $(ele).addClass('newRow');
            }
        })
    }
});
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var dataSource = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;
    var x = dataSource.insert(0, {
        "name":"ABC",
        "age": 99
    });
    newUUID.push("[data-uid='" + x.uid + "']");
    $("[data-uid='" + x.uid + "']").addClass('newRow');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look-up the newly added row by its UID and add the class to the row.

I explored the solution on this blog: [*"Simple Row Coloring in a KendoUI Grid"*](https://daveaglick.com/posts/simple-row-coloring-in-kendo-grid)

```js
const sampleData = getSampleData();

$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#example-grid-wrapper").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: sampleData.data,
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: sampleData.fields
        }
      }
    },
    columns: sampleData.columns
  });

  setTimeout(insertNewRecordAfterOneSecond, 1000);
});

function insertNewRecordAfterOneSecond() {
  // Insert data
  let dataGrid = $('#example-grid-wrapper').data('kendoGrid');
  dataGrid.dataSource.insert(0, { id: 1, name: "Sam", location: "B", color: "blue", status: 0 });
  
  // Re-scan table and lookup newly added row.
  dataGrid = $('#example-grid-wrapper').data('kendoGrid');
  let dataView = dataGrid.dataSource.view();
 
  for (let i = 0; i < dataView.length; i++) {
    if (dataView[i].id === 1) {
      dataGrid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataView[i].uid + "']").addClass("highlighted-row");
    }
  }
}

function getSampleData() {
  return {
    data : [
      { id: 2, name: "Grant",   location: "A", color: "green",  status: 1 },
      { id: 3, name: "Vaughan", location: "B", color: "red",    status: 0 },
      { id: 4, name: "David",   location: "A", color: "orange", status: 1 }
    ],
    fields : {
      id:       { type: "number" },
      name:     { type: "string" },
      location: { type: "string" },
      color:    { type: "string" }
    },
    columns : [
      { field: "id",       title: "ID",       width: "10%" },
      { field: "name",     title: "Name",     width: "30%" },
      { field: "location", title: "Location", width: "30%" },
      { field: "color",    title: "Color",    width: "20%" },
      { field: "status",   title: "Status",   width: "10%" }
    ]
  };
}
```

```css
.highlighted-row {
  background: #FF0; /* Higlight row yellow */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" />

<div id="example-grid-wrapper">
  <div id="example-grid"></div>
</div>
```

---

#### Alternative

As suggested by [gaetanoM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57501249/1762224).

```js
const sampleData = getSampleData();
var insertedUidList = [];

$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#example-grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: sampleData.data,
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: sampleData.fields
        }
      }
    },
    columns: sampleData.columns,
    // Suggested by gaetanoM
    dataBound: function(e) {
      $.each(insertedUidList, function(idx, uid) {
        // Re-apply class to existing rows.
        $(`tr[data-uid="${uid}"]`).addClass('highlighted-row');
      });
    }
  });

  // Insert two rows, one second apart.
  insertRowsWithDelay([
    { id: 0, name: "Joseph", location: "A", color: "yellow", status: 1 },
    { id: 1, name: "Sam", location: "B", color: "blue", status: 0 },
  ], 1000)
});

function insertRowsWithDelay(data, delayBetween) {
  if (data == null || data.length === 0) return;
  setTimeout(() => {
    insertNewRecord(data.pop());
    insertRowsWithDelay(data, delayBetween);
  }, 1000);
}

function insertNewRecord(record) {
  record = $('#example-grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.insert(0, record);
  insertedUidList.push(record.uid);
  $(`[data-uid="${record.uid}"]`).addClass('highlighted-row');
}

function getSampleData() {
  return {
    data : [
      { id: 2, name: "Grant",   location: "A", color: "green",  status: 1 },
      { id: 3, name: "Vaughan", location: "B", color: "red",    status: 0 },
      { id: 4, name: "David",   location: "A", color: "orange", status: 1 }
    ],
    fields : {
      id:       { type: "number" },
      name:     { type: "string" },
      location: { type: "string" },
      color:    { type: "string" }
    },
    columns : [
      { field: "id",       title: "ID",       width: "10%" },
      { field: "name",     title: "Name",     width: "30%" },
      { field: "location", title: "Location", width: "30%" },
      { field: "color",    title: "Color",    width: "20%" },
      { field: "status",   title: "Status",   width: "10%" }
    ]
  };
}
```

```css
.highlighted-row {
  background: #FF0; /* Higlight row yellow */
}
.highlighted-row.k-alt {
  background: #DD0; /* Higlight row yellow */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" />

<div id="example-grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a databound function for the grid and then try this inside the function

```js
    function onDataBound(e) {
      var dataSource = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
      var data = dataSource.data();
            $.each(data, function (index, rowItem) {
               if (data.length > 0) {
                  var rows = e.sender.tbody.children();
                   var row = $(rows[index]);
                   if (data[index].name == "ABC" ) {
                      row.addClass("NameColor");
                     }
                 }
              });
     }
```

```css
<style>
    .NameColor {
        background-color: black;
    }

</style>
```

Like this you can try..